# PySpark Union throws IllegalArgumentException: transpose requires all collections have the same size

Tags: pyspark

it's the first time I've seen this error when trying to union two Spark Dataframes.
I am trying to extract fraud records from existing data and then take a difference to get non-fraud cases and union the two but get the following error:

[image: union error]

Here's a snapshot of the DFs:

[image]

Happy to provide more info on DF operations if needed.
PySpark: 2.4.5
Python: 3.6.9

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why... but if you use `.distinct()` after union, will works:

```
res_df = df1.union(df2).distinct()
res_df.count()
```